# Правильно оформлено предложение с однородными членами?

Tags: однородные-члены

Это описание реки:

***Взобравшись на дамбу, я увидела движущуюся ленту, дорогу, уходившую за пределы кадра, за пределы мира.*** Если повезет, можно было увидеть баржи, большие плоские суда, которые скользили по реке – одни туда, другие обратно... (О. Токарчук "Бегуны"). Нобелевская премия и международный букер 2018 года. Издательство "Эксмо".

Вызывает сомнение правильность постановки второй запятой. И какая здесь интонация, перечислительная? Как это читать?

Answer (score 1):

Кажется, уловил мысль. Интересный случай.

Сначала хочется поставить тире (*лента — это дорога*), но по смыслу получается ерунда, так как одно другое не объясняет.

Это похоже на:
*Она умница, красавица.

Река — это лента, дорога.*

Интонация перечислительная. Слово "дорога" не уточняет слово "лента".
Два дополнения как бы описывают качества реки, проводится художественное сравнение с другими словами.

Comment: Спасибо, конечно, за ответ, oleedd. Рада вас слышать, но ведь опять - "поток сознания", а где ответ? Что это, интересный случай или грамматическая погрешность, которую желательно исправить? И... надо ли исправлять? Видите ли, автор очень любит перечислительную интонацию,  Образы мелькают в голове, вот и перечисляются...

Comment: Не вижу погрешности. Тире точно не подходит (по смыслу). Как вы сказали, это "один предмет, названный дважды разными именами". Перечисляем разные имена.

Comment: Тогда в скобках напишите (перечисляем разные имена).  Я при первом прочтении подумала, что разные предметы

Comment: Вот, о чем и речь.  Спасибо за понимание.

Comment: И ещё, эти слова вполне можно поменять местами, то есть уточнения там точно нет.

Answer (score 1):

По форме изложения и интонации это "поток сознания": перечисляется наблюдаемое в кадре в текущий момент изложения (возможно, "кадр" - в переносном смысле, если что-то заслоняет вид с боков) . Сначала привиделась какая-то движущаяся лента; присмотрелась - она похожа на дорогу. Ба - да это река! Она уходит куда-то. Можно смириться с перечислением через запятую осознаваемого последовательно. Но как-то "не по-нобелевски" выглядит начало следующего предложения: "Если повезет, можно было увидеть..." - так увидела или нет, повезло или была надежда на везение? Или в этом месте теоретически всякому может повезти когда-нибудь это увидеть? Диссонанс времен и совершенно-несовершенных видов на стыке двух предложений замутняет смысл второго.

Comment: Alex_ander, спасибо за ответ. Меня вот что не устраивает. Человек (ребенок) видит нечто. Это два предмета или один предмет, названный дважды разными именами? При перечислительной интонации - два предмета. Если один, то отношения между ними будут пояснительными (нужна пауза и тире), иначе варианты НЕ ОПРЕДЕЛЯЮТСЯ (при первом чтении, то есть надо возвращаться назад, осмысливать, а это не есть хорошо). И это я считаю серьезной погрешностью, которую нельзя оправдать авторским стилем.